# ContainerView add outlet

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicontainerview

I have a `ViewController` with a `Container View` that has an embedded `TableViewController`.

Now i would like to access the `TableView` in the `ViewController`, how can i make an outlet for that?

I tried to add the Container View as an outlet, but i can't access the embedded `TableViewController`.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't make an outlet directly because the table view is in a different scene (view controller), but you can access the tableview once you have a reference to the `UITableViewController` instance.  There are a couple of different ways of doing that.

First, you can use the `childViewControllers` property of your `UIViewController` subclass. If you know that there is only a single child then you can access it directly, otherwise you need to determine which is the correct child, say by looping through the array.

```
let myTableViewController = self.childViewControllers[0] as! UITableViewController
let theTableView = myTableViewController.tableView
```

The second option is to access the `UITableViewController` during the embed segue.  If you click on the embed segue in your storyboard you can give it an identifier as with any other segue.  Then you can implement `prepareForSegue` and grab the embedded `UITableViewController` instance -

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "tableviewEmbed") {
        let myTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! UITableViewController
        let theTableView = myTableViewController.tableView
    }
}
```

Personally, I prefer this second approach as I think it is 'cleaner'

Comment: Second approach rocks!

Answer (score 1):

Create outlet in child View Controller and access it using self.childViewControllers.lastObject (assuming you only have one child, otherwise use objectAtIndex:)